# Ruby Comparing scores

Tags: ruby, split

So I'm building a team ranking system in ruby. It will rank teams based upon how they do in head-to-head competition. Dodgers 3, Mariners 1 is my example score. I can split on the "," but to pull out the scores do I continue to split on the space between Dodgers and 3? Then I would need to recompile the strings. Is there a faster way to do this?

Here is my code so far:

```
 file = File.open($stdin.read)
    contents = ""
    file.each {|line|

    tokens = line.split(",")
    code = tokens[0]
    description = tokens[1]


     # handle spaces
     if tokens.count > 2
         description = tokens[1] + " " + tokens[2]
        end

     my_file = File.new("output.txt", "w")
        my_file.puts contents
}
```

Comment: "Recompile" the strings? You haven't changed the string.

Comment: Can you give some sample input and expected output? Can you clarify if team names can have spaces in them? Is `"The Rubees 3, Iron Pythons 4"` valid input?

Comment: Lions 1,  Awesome 1
Tarantulas 3, Snakes 1
Lions 4, Grouches 0

Comment: Is the `IO#each` block to contain additional code that makes use of the variables `tokens`, `code` and `description`? If so, you should say so; if not, those variables will no longer exist when the block is exited (unless they have been initialized before `each` is executed).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
file.each do |line|
  score1, score2 = line.split(',').map{|t| t.split(' ').last.to_i}
end
```

Comment: You could do this in one shot with a regular expression, or with this approach and iterate over things using `map`. Lots of opportunities to "DRY" this up.

Comment: As far as I can tell OP wants to use the scores within the block

Comment: I see. I moved my comment to the question.